# Does React.js have a basic Flux implementation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I am new to React.js and I am enjoying it a lot. I came across the Flux architecture while reading the React.js documentation. I understand that Flux is just a pattern and that there are many Flux implementations out there – including Facebook's own. I also know that React.js can be used without any Flux implementation.

My question is: is it safe to say that React.js has its own (small) Flux implementation embedded within it? In my opinion, I don't see any other way for React.js to achieve its uni-directional data-flow without having its own Flux implementation – which is, of course, replaceable with other Flux implementations.

Comment: It does not - reactjs is simply a rendering library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Flux** is pattern for handling application state and **React** is just view library. You don't have to use **Flux** with **React**, but it's preferred way.

Most popular Flux implementation seem to be **[Redux](https://egghead.io/series/getting-started-with-redux)** nowadays.

Comment: Yeah I totally got this. I' am basically thinking from some other perspective. In my opinion, when we listen for events on `React` components and we add action-handlers and in those action-handlers we manually call `setState` to update corresponding state(s), we are in some way implementing a very limited functionality of `Flux`. Although there are no proper `Dispatchers`, `Stores`, but our action-handlers are serving as both by listening for changes and updating component's state. I might not be correct in my way of thinking but thats how I' am mapping things.

Comment: React community slowly lean towards stateless components, where each state you are considering to store into `this.state` should be rather handled by Flux store.

Comment: As per your answer I have concluded, `React` like any other view library has it's own way of managing application state. But to get benefits of uni-directional data-flow (which `React` hasn't by-default), we need to use some `Flux` implementation like Facbook's Flux, Redux, Reflux etc. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer and comments. I' am marking your answer as the correct one :-).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The picture below is an explanation of what is, and what is not in react:

- The green stuff = part of React: a library to render a component tree in a DOM (or somewhere else).
- Unidirectional flow means that react is made for/ allows only top-down updates: any component can render/ update/ change itself (through change in state) or its children (through passing props down the tree).
- The blue parts are part of the Flux-pattern. React does not have any code/ library components for this.

[image]

The elements of flux make the circle complete: they allow react components to trigger actions, which in turn update stores, and can allow for (top) components to re-render based on changes in stores.
There are libraries (e.d. redux, reflux, alt) that implement the various elements of the flux architecture.